# Wrong number of arguments to ARRAYFORMULA. Expected 1 arguments, but got 2 arguments

Tags: hyperlink, arguments, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I am trying to perform a text replacement over multiple cells. I'm sure I can do this using ARRAYFORMULA, but i cant combine ARRAYFORMULA with HYPERLINK.

i have tried using

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(C2:C,HYPERLINK("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" & "&text=" & ENCODEURL(concatenate("Surat sudah dapat diambil di Balai Desa Kutorenon.")), "Send Whatsapp"))
```

but this gives a formula "Wrong number of arguments to ARRAYFORMULA. Expected 1 arguments, but got 2 arguments."

Answer (score 0):

What do you want with `C2:C`?

Just a guess:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" & C2:C & "&text=" & ENCODEURL("Surat sudah dapat diambil di Balai Desa Kutorenon."), "Send Whatsapp"))
```

Also, removed excessive `concatenate()`.